# Renaming iTunes music physical folders

Tags: itunes

I'm trying to rename folders containing iTunes music files.
How to safely update iTunes library to avoid missing tracks?

The reason why I need to rename folders:

- The music files are on a USB drive, and iTunes auto-tidying-up tricks don't seem to work.
- My folders are not named after the artist-album-track canon.

Comment: Why do you want to rename the folders?

Comment: If it's a case of tidying up artist/album names, change them in iTunes and iTunes will update the folder names automatically...

Comment: Do you have "keep media folders organised" & "copy to iTunes" on or off? prefs/advanced

Comment: @Tetsujin , See my updated question please.

Comment: @IconDaemon, See my updated question please.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly  See my updated question please.

Comment: ahh… OK, running it that way, every move you make to the file hierarchy will involve a doing a manual match-up in iTunes

Comment: Assuming you keep all your music on an external drive why not keep your iTunes library there as well? That way if you have the option for **keep media folders organised** as Tetsujin suggested, iTunes will keep everything correctly named *and* your files are still portable - if that's what you're aiming for...